# please help : nvidia 396.24.02 installation blocked

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 18.04

In my computer ubuntu 18.04 the installation of nvidia 396.24.02
do not work :

```
root@darioXPS:/home/dario# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up nvidia-dkms-396 (396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-396.24.02 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  nvidia
Version: 396.24.02
Kernel:  4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

nvidia.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-modeset.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-drm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-uvm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  nvidia
Version: 396.24.02
Kernel:  4.15.0-22-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

nvidia.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-modeset.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-drm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-uvm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.15.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 396.24.02
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-396.24.02 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-22-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-22-generic

$ ps aux | grep nvidia
root     13056  0.0  0.0   4628  1732 pts/1    S+   12:17   0:00 /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/nvidia-dkms-396.postinst configure 396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
root     13071  0.0  0.0   4628  1772 pts/1    S+   12:17   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/dkms/common.postinst nvidia 396.24.02 /usr/share/nvidia x86_64 396.24-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
root     14271  0.0  0.0  15336  5068 pts/1    S+   12:17   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 396.24.02 -k 4.15.0-22-generic -a x86_64
root     14277  0.0  0.0  16496  5416 pts/1   ks S+   12:17   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 396.24.02 -k 4.15.0-22-generic -a x86_64
dario    31265  0.0  0.0  15036  1096 pts/0    S+   13:20   0:00 grep nvidia
```

Please any suggestion ... thanks

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: The "error" is that procedure is "blocked" after few hours remain a that point :
Loading new nvidia-396.24.02 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-22-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-22-generic